# How to find the string between the second and third forward slashes?

Tags: java, regex

A device is sending to a MQTT broker a topic in the format:

```
gateway/device/variable/status
```

I want to extract, using JAVA Regex, each of the data between the forward slashes. So far I've managed to extract gateway, device and status. I'm having issues with the variable one. I'm using the site below to test the expressions:

https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Below are the expressions to extract the data already done:

gateway: `(^.*?)(?=\/)`

device: `(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\/.*\/)`

status: `[^/]+$`

When I try to extract variable, it comes with "device/variable" all together, using `(?<=/)(.*?)(?=/)` expression. I only want the variable part.

After extracting all four, I will build the variables in a Thingsboard-IoT Gateway application, which will parse the topics and populate the data.

Comment: You need to specify that the text between the slashes is anything but a slash `[^/]*`. Or maybe `+` instead of `*`, if it is required that there be at least one character.

Comment: Can't you just split on `/`?

Comment: Why not just use `String#split`?  Seems like it would be simpler solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd still use good 'ol `split`.
However, for the sake of challenge, this regex works as required:

```
(?<=\/)([^/]*?)(?=/[^/]*?$)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use extraction using regular expression for this, just split your string and access `result[2]` *after verifying* that the resultant array is in fact long enough for you to access that element.

```
String[] parts = url.split("/");
if (parts.length > 2 ) {
  // we know we can safely access our term
  ...
} else {
  // do something sensible here. You might think this'll never happen:
  // cool, account for it anyway.
}
```

Comment: *"no reason to use regular expressions"* but then you suggest using `split()`, which takes a regular expression as argument. Hmmm......

Comment: you commented as I was editing the answer to show using a normal string as argument.

Comment: `"/"` is a regex too. It just happens to not use any regex special characters, so the *effect* is a string match. The fact that the implementation has a performance boost for pure string regex's is besides the point. The value passed to the `split` method is still a regex pattern. If you forget that fact and change the argument to something that does contain a regex special character, your code will stop working correctly, so never forget that split's parameter is a regex. Should be easy to remember, since the parameter happens to be *named* **`regex`**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex, why extract them separately?

Write one regex to extract them all, e.g.

```
^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
```

As code:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)").matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
    String gateway  = m.group(1);
    String device   = m.group(2);
    String variable = m.group(3);
    String status   = m.group(4);
    // code here
}
```